# Use the same height for the image in deferment resolution in CSS

Tags: css

In the home screen I have an image, and this image when the resolution of the screen increments just like 3000x900 was stretch and does not display perfectly. so I want to know how I will keep the same max length in the deferment resolution in CSS for the image?

Image ID

```
font-family: 'Antenna Thin';
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 120%;
color:#FFFFFF;
margin-top: 3%;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
margin-left: -6%;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Its not too clear what you're asking, can you elaborate as to what the specific problem is, and provide all relevant code required to reproduce it?

Comment: Have you tried to use `max-width: 100%;` ?

Comment: in my current screen resolution every thing okay, but when try to use other resolution like (3000x900) some text will hidden because the hall image was stitch so, how i will use this problem by using @media in CSS?!!